# How to move rectangle to a defined coordinate in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

[picture of my Storyboard1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NShZo.png)
i create a button 'Start' that when we click on that button my rectangle will move to certain coordinates.Let say initial coordinate of rectangle is (0,0) then it will move to next node which has a coordinate of (20,45). Then it will move to another node which has a coordinate of (40,57).
There is no error when building the apps but whenever i click the button i come up with error 'System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'' All errors occur at all thetry-catch function. How i will going to code to make the rectangle move to these several coordinates? Below are my in code :

```
private void Button_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard s = this.FindResource("Storyboard1") as Storyboard;
        EasingDoubleKeyFrame kF = this.FindResource("Storyboard1") as EasingDoubleKeyFrame;


        string start = Start_Node.Text; //textbox Parent location
        string end = End_Node.Text; //textbox Kid location

        char nodeBegin = start[0];//initialize of nodeBegin & nodeEnd
        char nodeEnd = end[0];

        Graph test = new Graph();  //fill dictionary with key of node number, and value as a dictionary with connected nodes
        test.add('a', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'b', 5 }, { 'g', 7 } });
        test.add('b', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'a', 5 }, { 'c', 9 }, { 'd', 12 } });
        test.add('c', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'b', 9 } });
        test.add('d', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'b', 12 }, { 'e', 10 }, { 'h', 18 }, { 'i', 8 } });
        test.add('e', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'd', 10 } });
        test.add('f', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'h', 9 } });
        test.add('g', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'a', 7 }, { 'i', 16 } });
        test.add('h', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'd', 18 }, { 'f', 9 }, { 'j', 6 } });
        test.add('i', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'g', 16 }, { 'd', 8 }, { 'j', 19 } });
        test.add('j', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'i', 19 }, { 'h', 6 }, { 'k', 8 }, { 'l', 10 }, { 'm', 22 } });
        test.add('k', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'j', 8 }, { 'l', 3 } });
        test.add('l', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'k', 3 }, { 'j', 10 }, { 'm', 20 } });
        test.add('m', new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'j', 22 }, { 'l', 20 } });

        List<char> finalPath = test.shortPath(nodeBegin, nodeEnd); //get shortest path between two specific nodes in reverse order
        List<char> newFinal = new List<char>();
        int j = 0;
        int i = finalPath.Count;
        for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            newFinal.Add(finalPath[i]);
            j++;

        }

        newFinal.Insert(0, nodeBegin);  //add in starting node at beginning drawing purpose
        double[] AToB = new double[4] { 77, 280, 122, 270 };//x and y coordinates of each node location to allow for drawing of lines      
        double[] AToG = new double[4] { 77, 280, 92, 336 };
        double[] BToC = new double[4] { 150, 253, 150, 175 };
        double[] BToD = new double[4] { 191, 262, 315, 255 };
        double[] DToE = new double[4] { 340, 249, 330, 159 };
        double[] DToH = new double[4] { 370, 255, 528, 265 };
        double[] IToD = new double[4] { 350, 335, 345, 272 };
        double[] GToI = new double[4] { 150, 340, 330, 340 };
        double[] HToF = new double[4] { 560, 255, 560, 175 };
        double[] JToH = new double[4] { 580, 330, 580, 279 };
        double[] IToJ = new double[4] { 394, 340, 530, 340 };
        double[] JToK = new double[4] { 580, 350, 580, 405 };
        double[] LToJ = new double[4] { 670, 405, 595, 350 };
        double[] JToM = new double[4] { 595, 340, 685, 175 };
        double[] KToL = new double[4] { 625, 420, 665, 415 };
        double[] LToM = new double[4] { 685, 403, 685, 175 };
        //Returnpath
        double[] BToA = new double[4] { 122, 270, 77, 280 }; //x and y coordinates of each node location to allow for drawing of lines       
        double[] GToA = new double[4] { 92, 336, 77, 280 };
        double[] CToB = new double[4] { 150, 175, 150, 253 };
        double[] DToB = new double[4] { 315, 255, 191, 262 };
        double[] EToD = new double[4] { 330, 159, 340, 249 };
        double[] HToD = new double[4] { 528, 265, 370, 255 };
        double[] DToI = new double[4] { 345, 272, 350, 335 };
        double[] IToG = new double[4] { 330, 340, 150, 340 };
        double[] FToH = new double[4] { 560, 175, 560, 255 };
        double[] HToJ = new double[4] { 580, 279, 580, 330 };
        double[] JToI = new double[4] { 530, 340, 394, 340 };
        double[] KToJ = new double[4] { 580, 405, 580, 350 };
        double[] JToL = new double[4] { 595, 350, 670, 405 };
        double[] MToJ = new double[4] { 685, 175, 595, 340 };
        double[] LToK = new double[4] { 665, 415, 625, 420 };
        double[] MToL = new double[4] { 685, 175, 685, 403 };


        double result;

        //to draw lines
        for (i = 0; i < newFinal.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            switch (newFinal[i])
            {
                case 'a':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'b')
                    {
                        foreach (var ab in AToG)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(AToB);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'g')
                    {
                        foreach (var ag in AToG)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(AToG);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'b':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'a')
                    {
                        foreach (var ba in BToA)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(BToA);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'c')
                    {
                        foreach (var bc in BToC)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(BToC);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'd')
                    {
                        foreach (var bd in BToD)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(BToD);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'c':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'b')
                    {
                        foreach (var cb in CToB)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(CToB);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'd':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'b')
                    {
                        foreach (var db in DToB)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(DToB);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'e')
                    {
                        foreach (var de in DToE)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(DToE);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'h')
                    {
                        foreach (var dh in DToH)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(DToH);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'i')
                    {
                        foreach (var di in DToI)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(DToI);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'e':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'd')
                    {
                        foreach (var ed in EToD)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(EToD);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'f':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'h')
                    {
                        foreach (var fh in FToH)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(FToH);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'g':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'a')
                    {
                        foreach (var ga in GToA)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(GToA);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'i')
                    {
                        foreach (var gi in GToI)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(GToI);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'h':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'd')
                    {
                        foreach (var hd in HToD)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(HToD);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'f')
                    {
                        foreach (var hf in HToF)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(HToF);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'j')
                    {
                        foreach (var hj in HToJ)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(HToJ);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 'i':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'g')
                    {
                        foreach (var ig in IToG)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(IToG);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'd')
                    {
                        foreach (var id in IToD)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(IToD);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'j')
                    {
                        foreach (var ij in IToJ)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(IToJ);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 'j':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'i')
                    {
                        foreach (var ji in JToI)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(JToI);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'h')
                    {
                        foreach (var jh in JToH)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(JToH);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'k')
                    {
                        foreach (var jk in JToK)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(JToK);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'l')
                    {
                        foreach (var jl in JToL)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(JToL);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'm')
                    {
                        foreach (var jm in JToM)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(JToM);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'k':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'j')
                    {
                        foreach (var kj in KToJ)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(KToJ);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'l')
                    {
                        foreach (var kl in KToL)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(KToL);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;


                case 'l':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'k')
                    {
                        foreach (var lk in LToK)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(LToK);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'j')
                    {
                        foreach (var lj in LToJ)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(LToJ);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'm')
                    {
                        foreach (var lm in LToM)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(LToM);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 'm':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'j')
                    {
                        foreach (var mj in MToJ)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(MToJ);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'l')
                    {
                        foreach (var ml in MToL)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = Convert.ToDouble(MToL);
                                kF.Value = result;
                            }

                            catch (FormatException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert to a Double.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }


        s.Begin(this);
    }
```

Comment: In your [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) statements, `foreach (var ab in AToG)` for example, you want `result = Convert.ToDouble(ab);`, etc....

Comment: I already edit it but it come with error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' " And it highlighting the kF.Value = result;

Comment: You definitely  should redesign your data struct, you can make this work, and we could help you, but your code here is a little monster. For each modify you will want to do in this code in future, you will need to learn again what so you mean, when you was writing this code. Try to make this some another way, You have too much code. And why would you convert double array to double? How would it work? And how does your "Storyboard1" look like?

Comment: Btw. You can't have key "Storyboard1" for both, keyFrame and storyboard, there is no way to declare two elements with same key in same scope.

Comment: @sTrenat i aware with my code that a little bit mess but i will try to simplify it soon. i want to convert double array to double because i want  to set the array(coordinates) into EasingDoublekeyframe so that the keyframe can move the rectangle according the coordinate in the array. btw i have put the image of my storyboard at the question part above.

Comment: Here is sample animation of position: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bd4ad70d-275d-4cb6-8719-3aaecd89bd37/animate-translatetransform-property-of-a-grid-control?forum=wpf 
You just need to use e.g. TranslateTransofrm as your KeyFrame to make this work, not just Convert.Double( "make some thing with hope this will magicly work"). Firstly check what your e.g BToC means, do you realy need 4 coordinates? I'm sure you need just 2 of them..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with these lines of code, but your exception is somewhere in these lines:

```
result = Convert.ToDouble(AToG);
result = Convert.ToDouble(BToA);
result = Convert.ToDouble(BToC);
//... and other such lines
```

You can *NOT* convert **double[]** to **IConvertable**

For example your `AToG = new double[4] { 77, 280, 92, 336 }`

Then you can calculate your result as sum of the elements.

Or you can change the type of result to: **double[]**, and assign it just like `result = AToG`

Comment: Yes, but still i have to set the 'result' into double to assign to kF.Value so that i can i give the coordinates to EasingDoubleKeyFrame for the rectangle to move. So, how i'm suppose to convert double[] to double, actually?

Comment: @red **double[]** has *4 numbers* in it, how you can think to convert 4 numbers to 1 number??

Lets say you have { 1, 3, 5, 7 } how you can convert them to 9 ?

You can do maths with them: (7-1)+(5-3)=9

That is the only way to make one number of an array: perform some kind of calculations

Comment: Yes i got your point. But the 4 numbers are actually the coordinates of 2 nodes {x1,y1,x2,y2}. So do you have any idea to make the rectangle move based on the coordinates?